# Repository injection in an handler spring boot class performance

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm wondering about the best approach to inject the repository class into one of my utility classes, or rather a handler, to query the database. I approached it with this style:by injecting the repository into the configuration and then passing it to the component class. But is it the best way?

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AuthorizationConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
                new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new PermissionEvaluator(userRepository));
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

So in the component I use the UserRepository Injected:

```
@Component
public class PermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {


    private UserRepository UserRepository;

    public PermissionEvaluator(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.UserRepository = UserRepository;
    }

// methods with the repo for interact with database
private boolean hasPrivilege(Authentication auth, String permission)  {
    String username = auth.getName();
   User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
```

1. It' this injection performant?
2. There is a best way to do that?
3. There is a way to inject directly in the PermissionEvaluator class?

Thanks

Comment: It will perform ok, but this is not correct.  Marking `PermissionEvaluator` as `@Component` will make it a bean.  Therefore, you should be autowiring that into `AuthorizationConfiguration`, not newing it up.  If you ever find yourself doing `new` on a class that's a bean, then you've got something wrong.